# PHP xml - concatenate severals files in one

Tags: php, xml

I have 4 xml files and I want to create one unique file with the content of each files except the 2 first lines and the last line.

Details:

my xml files:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Client>
    <client_id>123458</client_id>
    <client_type>People</client_type>
    <client_sub_type>Sub people</client_sub_type>
    <name>Alerich</name>
    <surname>Higor</surname>
 </Client>
 <Client>
    <client_id>5487</client_id>
    <client_type>People</client_type>
    <client_sub_type>Sub people</client_sub_type>
    <name>Newman</name>
    <surname>Matew</surname>
 </Client>
 </Clients>
```

1.xml, 2.xml, 3.xml and 4.xml have a content like this.

And i want to create a final.xml file which start with

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

end with:

```
 </Clients>
```

and between theses lines i want all  lines for fourth files.

Have you some tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP DOM function to achieve this:

```
$d1 = new DOMDocument();
$d1->load('1.xml');
$root = $d1->getElementsByTagName('Clients')->item(0);

// List of other xml files
$files = array('2.xml', '3.xml', '4.xml');

foreach($files as $file) {
    $d2 = new DOMDocument();
    $d2->load($file);
    foreach($d2->getElementsByTagName('Client') as $elem) {
        $newNode = $d1->importNode($elem, true);
        $root->appendChild($newNode);
    }
}
$d1->saveXMLFile('newfile.xml'));
```

A general tip: **Don't make any assumptions on line breaks in XML files!** So your premise of "first two lines and last line of the file" may be wrong. Using XML functions instead of string functions avoids these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Read the files with `fgets` and check for the xml or clients tag with `preg_match`. If the line doesn't match, write the line to the new file. Of course you have to place a new xml and clients tag around the new file.